# Erro ao montar String com parâmetro .NET

Tags: html, html5, .net, string, asp.net-core

Então galera, estou desenvolvendo um projeto com .NET Core Razor, e estou montando uma string la, da seguinte maneira:

```
string TotalInformacoes = "";
TotalInformacoes += (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cl_1.Trim()) ? "/CLIENTE:" + cl_1 : "");
TotalInformacoes += "ÿ";
```

cl_1 é um parametro que estou recebendo quando executo um post, e no caso deste teste, estou deixando o campo vazio propositalmente. É um input type text.

quando eu debugo o código consigo ver que o cl_1 está nulo, mas por algum motivo, está dando este erro no meu navegador:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

E me mostra em vermelho esta linha:

```
TotalInformacoes += (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cl_1.Trim()) ? "/CLIENTE:" + cl_1 : "";
```

Como esta no print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1:** Código do OnPost:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string cl_1, string dt_in)
{
    string TotalInformacoes = "";
    TotalInformacoes = checkDataInicial == "1" ? "/DI:" + dt_in : "";
    TotalInformacoes += (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cl_1.Trim()) ? "/CLIENTE:" + cl_1 : "");
    TotalInformacoes += "ÿ";

    return Page();
}
```

Input:

```
<input name="cl_1" id="cl_1" class="form-control pl-2" type="text">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dt_in" name="dt_in">
```

Comment: Antes que perguntem, este input não está como required

Comment: @Maniero, acho que o link que vc passou não tem a resposta do que eu preciso. O erro é o mesmo, mas são situações diferentes, inclusive o dele é em um get. Eu consigo ver o valor desta minha variável, através de um debug.

Comment: A sua pergunta também não tem o código necessário para identificar onde está o erro. Com uma pergunta genérica a resposta acaba sendo genérica. Essas respostas tem um problema igual e explicação porque o erro ocorre, então assim você consegue resolver no seu código. lendo isso aprenderá que esse erro sempre é gerado em outro lugar, e aí poderá aprender não cometê-lo mais que é o mais importante que uma solução pontual.

Comment: O meu erro está neste local sim. Se eu comento a linha, o post é feito normalmente @Maniero

Comment: @Maniero, editei a pergunta colocando o código.

Comment: @Lima, veja que você não está recebendo nada para `cl_1` em seu método, debugue o seu código, veja que que se você atribuir um valor default para o parâmetro, o erro não vai acontecer `OnPost(string cl_1="")`...Mas isso ainda não fará o seu código funcionar... talvez um `[FromBody]` ajude, mas leia as outras perguntas apontadas pelo Maniero e entenda o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre pois o parâmetro esta null, conforme você mencionou, e você esta chamando o `String.IsNullOrEmpty` mas na hora de passar o campo no parâmetro do método você chama o Trim, então a primeira coisa a ser executada é o Trim, e o Trim espera que o valor nunca seja null, por isso você o erro de `NullReferenceException`.

Você pode usar o `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, que verifica se o texto não e nulo e não é apenas espaços em branco:

```
(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cl_1) ? "/CLIENTE:" + cl_1 : "");
```

Caso queira saber melhor o que esses métodos fazem, você pode ver o fonte deles aqui:

[IsNullOrEmpty](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23a8597f842071f4)

[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef)

Comment: Funcionou... então o erro estava no meu `Trim()` não no `IsNullOrEmpty`. Entendi, obrigado